# PayPal payment using credit card stored in vault PHP

Tags: php, paypal

I have an id of credit card details which is saved in paypal vault `CARD-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`. I need to make a payment with this card using php-paypal-SDK. For this purpose I have written bellow code.

```
<?php
require 'PayPal-PHP-SDK-master/vendor/autoload.php';

$clientId       = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$clientSecret   = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;
use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;
use PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\FundingInstrument;
use PayPal\Api\CreditCard;
use PayPal\Api\CreditCardToken;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;


$sdkConfig = array(
    "mode" => "sandbox"
);

$apiContext =  $apiContext = new ApiContext(new OAuthTokenCredential(
    $clientId,
    $clientSecret
));

$credit_card_token = new CreditCardToken();
$credit_card_token->setCreditCardId('CARD-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

$fundinginstrument = new FundingInstrument();
$fundinginstrument->setCreditCardToken($credit_card_token);


$payer     = new Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod('credit_card');
$payer->setFundingInstruments(array($fundinginstrument));

$payment    = new Payment();

$payment->setIntent('sale');

$payment->setPayer($payer);

$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount('10.00');
$transaction->setDescription('Test payment');
$payment->setTransactions(array($transaction));

$request = clone $payment;

try {
    $output = $payment->create($apiContext);
    print_r($output);

} catch (PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $pce) {

    echo '<pre>';print_r(json_decode($pce->getData()));exit;
    exit(1);
}
```

But it throws error as follows

> **MALFORMED_REQUEST** - Incoming JSON request does not map to API request

what was wrong with this code?This is the first time i am dealing with this SDK.

Comment: Likely there is a problem with the JSON: have you inspected it?

Comment: @Richard  $amount = new Amount();
 $amount->setCurrency('USD');
 $amount->setTotal('10.00');  pass this as amount fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

If still not working then you can use `curl` or any HTTP client. For the demonstration, I used [GuzzleHttp](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle)

```
$uri      = 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token';
$clientId = 'CLIENT_ID';
$secret   = 'CLIENT_SECRET';

$client   = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('POST', $uri, [
    'headers' =>
    [
        'Accept'          => 'application/json',
        'Accept-Language' => 'en_US',
        'Content-Type'    => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    ],
    'body'    => 'grant_type=client_credentials',

    'auth'    => [$clientId, $secret, 'basic'],
]
);

$data = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);

$access_token = $data['access_token'];

$payment_uri = 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment';
$data        = '{
  "intent": "sale",
  "payer": {
    "payment_method": "credit_card",
    "funding_instruments": [
    {
      "credit_card_token": {
        "credit_card_id": "CREDIT_CARD_ID"
      }
    }]
  },
  "transactions": [
  {
    "amount": {
      "total": "10.00",
      "currency": "USD"
    },
    "description": "Payment by vaulted credit card."
  }]
}';
$payment = $client->request('POST', $payment_uri, [
    'headers' =>
    [
        'Content-Type'  => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $access_token,
    ],
    'body'    => $data,
]
);

$transaction = json_decode($payment->getBody(), true);

echo "<pre>";

print_r($transaction);
```

Follow [this](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/vault/#pay-with-vaulted-card)  link to read more details. If you need further help you can comment here or [linkedin](https://www.linkedin.com/in/md-abu-ahsan-basir/), [github](https://github.com/maab16) or [instagram](https://www.instagram.com/abuahsanbasir/)

Good luck